# What is the default timezone setting for a web application?

Tags: 2010, timer-jobs, web-application, timezone

We have a sharepoint server that is in pacific time. There are several webapps and they do not have a timezone specified (Manage Web Application > Web Application > General Settings > Default timezone) is empty. We have set the timer jobs to run in pacific time. Lets say a timer job is set to 7 AM, when I check the status, the text says "Timer job completed at 10:00 AM", even though its not 10 am yet. Obviously it is showing EST. There are several timer jobs that are running and some are hanging at different percentages.

My question is, whats the default timezone of a timer job, when a web application value is not set?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default value for timer jobs is the server time zone when you first install SharePoint.  Changing it is a little complex but doable... Biggest pain is clearing configuration cache.

https://blog.azaleos.com/sharepoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=20

Comment: Thanks, the first line answers my question. Im not looking at changing the tz-s right away, though configuration cache dir does not exist. Can it be somewhere else? How will I find that?